# Change the event display on fullcalendar - Full duration should not be highlighted

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a very specific use case.

The customer would like these types of timeslots available on the calendar:

08:30
08:30
08:30

08:45

09:45

10:00
10:00

So three appointments can be made for 08:30, only 1 for 08:45, only 1 for 9:45 and 2 for 10:00.
These appointments can be of variable durations.

I have therefore set the AgendaDay grid view, to show a label in 15 minute intervals.

I plan to add a comment on a particular timeslot, saying that only 3 appointments can be booked here. And, I will make the inbetween timeslots unavailable to book. Not sure on the best way to do this but I will figure that part out.

Where I am getting stuck, is that I would need the event\booking to only display at the time of the booking, regardless of the duration of the appointment, i.e if a booking is made at 08:30, only the 08:30 - 08:45 line should be highlighted, even if the appointment is 2 ours long. I do not want a big block taking over the following time slots. I hope that makes sense.

I have tried eventDisplay: 'list-item', but this is not working and I need it to display in the same way for all views, i.e. day, week and month

I have tried googling and am unable to find a solution.

Am I perhaps missing something obvious? Or does anyone have any thoughts please?

Thank,
Regards,
LJR

Comment: "will make the inbetween timeslots unavailable to book"...I'd recommend using Background Events for that job

Comment: "only the 08:30 - 08:45 line should be highlighted"... I suggest telling fullCalendar that the event is only 15 minutes long, and storing the real end time in another field in the event object. You could even add it to the description shown on the event instead

Comment: Thank you so much ADyson - I actually ended up coming up with that solution in the end too. Appreciate you feedback.

Comment: Am I allowed to ask another different question here? I know people are pedantic on this platform. I just wanted to know if there is a way to align a particular event to always stay at the far left of the calendar? Kind of like a 'label for that time slot' ?

Comment: If the event is the only event in that timeslot, it'll be on the left always. If it's not, it'll be displayed as per the eventOrder rules - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder . Not sure what you mean by "label for that time slot" though - what information are you trying to convey, exactly?

Comment: i'm sure I can make eventOrder work for me somehow. Eg. for the 8:30 am slot, I want to have a label or warning saying - 'Book ONLY 4 reservations in this time slot' - to prevent staff from overbooking a particular time slot.

Comment: and yes, i've noticed this functionality, it is always on the left when the only event, but if bookings are made, the order becomes muddled - your answer regarding eventOrder rules has already helped me though :)

Comment: Well not entirely, but i'm looking into you EventOrder suggestion.

Comment: "to prevent staff from overbooking a particular time slot." Well it's a useful warning but it won't actually prevent anything. That can be done by your server validating every booking before it saves it, to check the number of existing bookings in that slot

Comment: I intend to implement validation too but the client wants a visual representation as well. Thanks for your input, I'll continue to try to get eventOrder working. Have a lovely day.